# How do I make line symbols intersect cleanly without showing edges in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style, line

I digitised a map showing electric grid lines. I merged a number of lines into a single feature. Now, I'd like these lines to be displayed so that the intersections appear continuous. At the moment, the line edges on intersections are visible and it's not pretty, as visible on the screenshot below:

[image: Overlapping line borders at intersections]

I could swear I've seen something about this somewhere on the Internet but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use Symbol Levels:

[image]

[image]

The higher the number the later is it drawn. So black will be rendered first then the purple over top meaning that any black bits will be rendered over.

[image]