# QGIS styling - displaying an outline around line features in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am trying to symbolize a road network in QGIS.

Currently I am using a pen width of 1.86 milimeters to symbolize the roads, however I would also like to outline the roads with a secondary color.

This is easily done for polygons, however I cannot figure out if it is also possible with line features.

Another solution would be to use a buffer to generate polygons from the roads, however this is not optimal, so I would like to avoid this.

FINAL EDIT: I do not think this question exactly has been answered before, at least I couldn't find it. However, the answers in the linked questions could also be applied for my case.

Comment: @iant, I don't think it is a duplicate because it refers to symbology and not to labels.

Comment: I was looking at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163651/styling-segmented-cased-lines-in-qgis which is a dup too

Comment: @iant I think the op is after a multicolour line symbol and this isn't answered in any of the two questions you refer. Rather the questions are dealing with the next step

Comment: I agree that it is very similar, however I think this question may be relevant still, as I could not find the other questions when looking for an answer.

Comment: Agreed your question starts one step sooner - how to visually make outline for line feature. That step is covered in the answers of other questions but hard to find as the questions do not contain line and outline keyword.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve my problem in the following way:

I ended ud using two simple line symbologies, one slightly wider than the other.

[image]

This does not look great on segmented roads however, as illustrated here: [image] 
After enabling Symbol Levels, a good result is achieved, as seen here:
[image]

I also found that applying a "Round" Cap style for the lines eliminated some "gaps" in the symbology that appeared at some points where the lines merged.